# Search for a value in tuple of lists/vectors

Tags: haskell

I guess there is some smarter way to implement such simple piece of code, but I couldn't figure out other solution by myself. Could it be done recursively without some sort of `if`'s?

```
import           Data.Vector (Vector)
import qualified Data.Vector

type SeqV = (Vector Integer, Vector Integer, Vector Integer)

seqv :: SeqV
seqv = (Data.Vector.fromList[1..5], Data.Vector.fromList[10..15], Data.Vector.fromList[20..25])

-- | searchs for n in SeqV from left to right
-- returns first found value
find :: Integer -> SeqV -> Maybe Integer
find n (a,b,c) =
  case f a of
       Just v -> Just v
       Nothing -> case f b of
         Just v  -> Just v
         Nothing -> f c

  where f v = let f = Data.Vector.filter (==n) v
                  in if Data.Vector.length f > 0 then
                                               Just (Data.Vector.head f)
                                               else Nothing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find :: Integer -> SeqV -> Maybe Integer
find n (a,b,c) | elem n a || elem n b || elem n c = Just n
find _ _ = Nothing
```

There's also `(<|>) :: Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a` and `asum :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe a`, but if you simplified your question and `find` above doesn't unsimplify, post the whole code and there might be an unreasonably short answer again. I also have the feeling wherever you use `find` could be simplified further since `find` only really returns a boolean.